# Sqlite 3 won't install in Mono Linux

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, nuget

I made a project and I used sqlite 3.0 in Visual Studio.It was mandatory to change to Linux because my school uses it so I passed the code to Mono that runs c# at Linux.When I used Nuget to download sqlite I got this:

> The 'sqlite 3.13.0' package requires Nuget client version '2.12' or
>   above, but the current Nuget version is '2.8.7.0'.

I 've searched a lot for a fix with no luck.Is there another way to install sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the Nuget CIL-assembly by executing:

```
sudo nuget update -self
```

Currently that will update Nuget to `3.5.0`

i.e.

```
>sudo nuget update -self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.12.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 3.5.0.
```

Comment: Sorry,there is still a problem.Nuget v-3 was installed in terminal but within mono development software I still get the exact same message and when I try to install via terminal I get this

Comment: An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Json.NET' from source 'Official NuGet Gallery'.
  The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/FindPackagesById()?id='Json.NET'' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.

Comment: NuGet feed v3 (VS 2015 / NuGet v3.x): https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json